# How to fetch 2 rows at a time from MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table user

```
user(id, username, email, profile_pic) // Id is primary key
```

Now I want to fetch result, two rows at a time on each iterations in PHP code because i need to display two rows from database.
I want to display my result as given in below way.

**Example**

```
user1     user2
user3     user4
user5     user6
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The proper way to do that would be to select all rows you want to display and let your programming language do the formatting. However, without providing what programming language you are using, providing further assistance will be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to join the user table to
itself and to do that according to your 
rule. So here is the code. Try it out.

--- DATA ---

```
    create table user(id int, username varchar(100), email varchar(100), profile_pic varchar(100));

    insert into user
    (id , username , email , profile_pic )
    values
    (10, 'user1', 'x1@x.com', '111');


    insert into user
    (id , username , email , profile_pic )
    values
    (20, 'user2', 'x2@x.com', '222');

    insert into user
    (id , username , email , profile_pic )
    values
    (30, 'user3', 'x3@x.com', '333');

    insert into user
    (id , username , email , profile_pic )
    values
    (40, 'user4', 'x4@x.com', '444');

    insert into user
    (id , username , email , profile_pic )
    values
    (50, 'user5', 'x5@x.com', '555');

    insert into user
    (id , username , email , profile_pic )
    values
    (60, 'user6', 'x6@x.com', '666');


    insert into user
    (id , username , email , profile_pic )
    values
    (70, 'user7', 'x7@x.com', '777');
```

--- QUERY 1 ---

```
    SELECT v1.ID as id1, v1.email as email1, v2.ID as id2, v2.email as email2

    FROM

    (

    SELECT
        @i:=@i+1 AS num,
        u.*
    FROM
        (SELECT u1.* FROM USER u1 ORDER BY u1.id ASC) u,
        (SELECT @i:=0) AS tbl

    ORDER BY num ASC

    ) v1


    JOIN


    (

    SELECT
        @j:=@j+1 AS num,
        u.*
    FROM
        (SELECT u1.* FROM USER u1 ORDER BY u1.id ASC) u,
        (SELECT @j:=0) AS tbl

    ORDER BY num ASC

    ) v2 ON ( v1.num = v2.num - 1 AND mod(v1.num, 2) = 1);
```

If you want to also get the last row (the one with ID = 7) do this.

--- QUERY 2 ---

```
    SELECT v1.ID as id1, v1.email as email1, v2.ID as id2, v2.email as email2

    FROM

    (SELECT v0.* FROM 
            (

            SELECT
                @i:=@i+1 AS num,
                u.*
            FROM
                (SELECT u1.* FROM USER u1 ORDER BY u1.id ASC) u,
                (SELECT @i:=0) AS tbl

            ORDER BY num ASC

            ) v0 WHERE MOD(v0.num, 2) = 1 
    ) v1 

    LEFT JOIN


    (

    SELECT
        @j:=@j+1 AS num,
        u.*
    FROM
        (SELECT u1.* FROM USER u1 ORDER BY u1.id ASC) u,
        (SELECT @j:=0) AS tbl

    ORDER BY num ASC

    ) v2 ON ( v1.num = v2.num - 1 );
```

Comment: thanks all for the help. But his answer is right because i do not need to do much effort to run his code.

Comment: Add `insert into user (id , username , email , profile_pic ) values
(70, 'user1', 'x6@x.com', '777');` and you see, that your result does not change. You miss the last row.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fetch two rows in one time. You need to correctly create your view script.

```
$counter=0;
echo '<table><tr>';
while($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $counter++;
    echo '<td>'.$row['user'].'</td>';
    if ($counter%2 == 0) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
}

if ($counter%2 == 1) {
    echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>'
}

echo '</tr></table>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The eassiest way would be load all your users in an array in PHP and use the following pseudo code withing PHP:

Assume your array of users has an index from 0 to the ammount of users.
The value you should reference in each cell (x = 0-rows , y = 0-cols)
CellValue ( x+1+y)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

No need to modify the way you fetch data. Here follows a plaintext, short and simple solution, resolved using frontend code only:

```
$rownum = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $rownum++;
    echo $row['username'] . ($rownum %2 == 0) ? "\n" : '     ');
}
```

Comment: Check you variable names. `$rownum` vs `$counter`.